# trying to implement sudoku solver brute foce algorithm

Tags: python

I've been trying to implement the brute force part of this http://www.garshol.priv.no/blog/178.html in my program here: http://paste.pound-python.org/show/7107/, but I'm relatively inexperience and I've hit a wall. I understand *generally* whats going on in the algorithm but I can't figure out where I'm going wrong.

Comment: So what's the question? What is the wall you've hit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out Peter Norvig's python sudoku solution. It's both more elegant and clearer imho.
http://norvig.com/sudoku.html

Comment: +1 for beating me to the link.

Comment: I have seen it, but I thought it was a lot harder to understand. I'll have another look, but for the moment I'd prefer to implement a less _well done_ brute-forcing approach.

Comment: @Jarvis-Walker leave brute force to C++. Python is better suited to elegance.

Answer (score 1):

maybe you want to try implimenting [Dancing Links algorithm](http://users.tkk.fi/~aajanki/sudoku/index.html)

more information about [Dancing Links](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dancing_Links)

Comment: +1 for introducing a cool algorithm I never heard of before!